# Unable to read attribute in Linq to xml, error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am new in Linq to xml. My xml string is as follows :

```
 <root>
    <add>
       <item id="jqg1" moduleid="F0736590-84A2-4795-BC5D-0056606F2446" view="1" add="1" edit="0" del="0" /> 
    </add>
   <update>
        <item id="jqg3" moduleid="3C414435-DBBE-4B4E-A790-14B67F050EB0" view="1" add="1" edit="1" del="0" /> 
    </update>
  </root>
```

coming from jquery to C# which is placed inside texbox(textbox Visible = false).

**NOTE** : element could be more than one in every  and  element.

Code to read xml string in C# on button click eevnt.

```
string paramXML = txtXmlStr.Text;
var l_sID = "";
var l_sMODID = "";
var l_sVIEW = ""; 
var l_sADD = "";
var l_sEDIT = "";
var l_sDEL = "";

if (!string.Empty.Equals(paramXML))
{
    var l_oXDoc = XDocument.Parse(paramXML.ToLower());

    ==> var addParams = from addParam in l_oXDoc.Element("add").Elements("item")
                        select new
                        {
                            l_sID = addParam.Attribute("id").Value,
                            l_sMODID = addParam.Attribute("moduleId").Value,
                            l_sVIEW = addParam.Attribute("view").Value,
                            l_sADD = addParam.Attribute("add").Value,
                            l_sEDIT = addParam.Attribute("edit").Value,
                            l_sDEL = addParam.Attribute("del").Value,
                        };

        foreach (var oParam in addParams)
        {
            string id = oParam.l_sID.Trim();
            string modid = oParam.l_sMODID.Trim();
            string view = oParam.l_sMODID.Trim();
            string add = oParam.l_sMODID.Trim();
            string edit = oParam.l_sMODID.Trim();
            string del = oParam.l_sMODID.Trim();
        }
```

I am getting above error on arrow which I already specified in code. How should I resolve this error???

**NOTE:**My goal is to read `<Add>` element's `<item>` element data into one variable and I also want to do same for `<update>` element. Is that possible.... everyones suggestion, ideas and code is welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the root element first. Change:

```
var addParams = from addParam in l_oXDoc.Element("add").Elements("item")
```

To

```
var addParams = from addParam in 
l_oXDoc.Descendants("root").First().Element("add").Elements("item")
```

Comment: Your suggestion work for me.Problem is solved.Thanx to give your precious time to read my prblem and give suggestion for this..But I have one more question and I hope you will suggest me some nice solution.Here in my xml string, both <add></add> element and <update></update> element(next <delete></delete> is also going to come in xml string), all have inside same <item></item> element. So how I manage to write a code to read all those <add>, <update>, <delete> element's <item> element attribute with same 
`var addParams = from addParam in l_oXDoc.Element("").Elements("item") select`

Answer (score 1):

Attributes/Elements names are case sensitive.

Replace

```
l_sMODID = addParam.Attribute("moduleId").Value,
```

With

```
l_sMODID = addParam.Attribute("moduleid").Value,
```

That's because attributes in your input XML is `moduleid="F0736590-84A2-4795-BC5D-0056606F2446"`, not `moduleId`.

**Working code:**

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");

Func<XElement, IEnumerable<Item>> query = e => e.Elements("item")
                       .Select(x => new Item
                       {
                           Id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                           ModuleId = (string)x.Attribute("moduleid"),
                           View = (bool)x.Attribute("view"),
                           Add = (bool)x.Attribute("add"),
                           Edit = (bool)x.Attribute("edit"),
                           Delete = (bool)x.Attribute("del")
                       });

var addItems = query(doc.Root.Element("add")).ToList();
var updateItems = query(doc.Root.Element("update")).ToList();
```

`Item` class declaration:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ModuleId { get; set; }
    public bool View { get; set; }
    public bool Add { get; set; }
    public bool Edit { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanx to show my mistake... I correct it but still problem persist...waiting for more suggestions...

Comment: I've updated my answer with working code which does what I think you're asking about.

Comment: You solved my whole problem. Thanx a lot MarcinJuraszek... I want one more suggestion from you and I hope you will give me. To read all data from `var addItems and updateItems` i have to code separate `foreach` loop for variables. Is there any logic to read all,addItems and updateItems data by using one `foreach` loop..

Comment: `var addAndUpdateItems = query(doc.Root.SelectMany(r => new[] { r.Element("add"), r.Element("update") }));`

Comment: Or change `query` to be `e.Descendants("item")` instead of `e.Elements("item")` and call it with `doc.Root`: `query(doc.Root)`

Comment: I just want to know that, please don't feel bad for this question, according to performance wise which method is good; your method or my method. I am asking this because your code is looking more complex than mine... so kindly reply for my this question...

Comment: The performance will be similar. The only difference is sharing the query definition for getting results from both `add` and `update` nodes.

Comment: Ok sir.... The one thing I want to notice you is that your `var addAndUpdateItems = query(doc.Root.SelectMany(r => new[] { r.Element("add"), r.Element("update") }));` code is giving error and that is `System.xml.Linq.XElement does not contain definition for 'SelectMany' and no extenstion method 'SelectMany' accepting a first argument of type System.xml.Linq.XElement could be found`